# Why does the output voltage of an alternator increases when it is connected to Capacitive load?

Tags: generator, alternator

Why does an alternator output voltage gets **higher** when it is connected to **capacitive** load than it was with a **inductive** or **resistive** load?

I understand that when a capacitive load is connected it **improves the power factor**. But how does power factor increases output voltage?

Is there any **resonance** effect when a capacitive load is connected? And if so how does that affect the output voltage?

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent circuit of an alternator consists of the an ideal AC voltage generator in series with a "source impedance" which can be modelled by a resistor in series with an inductor. When this impedance is shunted with a capacitor, then, for a certain range of values of the R, L, and C components, a "resonant rise" in the voltage across the inductor will occur, with the result that the overall output voltage is increased.

Comment: You mean RLC series resonance ? Can you draw a schematic or so ?