# Power generator and idle air conditioners voltage increase

Tags: voltage, power-generation

Today we faced the interesting issue.

There’s an office building with the backup gasoline power generator (non-inverter 7500 W max). The load on average is around 5000-6000 W.

During the power outage today the generator was launched and was producing 230 V without the load. When loaded it was giving normal 220 V. But at some point we noticed, that the voltage becomes 275-280 V, which causes a lot of issues with automatic devices overvoltage protection.

We started switching down line by line and detected that only a couple of lines cause the voltage increase. These were the lines with air conditioners, which were just in stand-by mode. When we switched all of them off (12 items), the voltage returned to the standard 220 V. This resolved the issue.

So my question is, why did that happen? Maybe somebody can elaborate?

Comment: You said 230V. Is the building supplied with 3-phase power?  Is the generator a 3-phase generator?

Comment: Generator is 1-phase. Building is 3-phase, but before using the generator there is a switch, which merges phases into 1 in order to work with 1-phase generator.

Answer (score 3):

Do your air conditioners have power factor correction (PFC) capacitors that are permanently in circuit rather than only connected when their motors are active?

If so a capacitive load on a synchronous generator can cause the off-load voltage to rise due to resonance between the capacitance and the generator inductance ([1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/345116/102667), [2](https://www.quora.com/When-a-capacitive-load-is-connected-to-a-generator-how-is-the-terminal-voltage-greater-than-the-excitation-voltage)). When the circuit is under load the load acts to dampen the resonance.

A fix would be to reconnect the PFC capacitors after the motor switching but you should only do so after discussing this with the manufacturer of the air conditioners and ensuring you comply with your local wiring code. Note that this might reduce the life of the [motor contactors](https://www.mikeholt.com/mojonewsarchive/All-HTML/HTML/Capacitors-Line-or-Load-Side-of-Motor-Disconnect%7E20000125.php).

A simpler, if less comfortable, solution would be to turn off the lines to the air conditioners when you are running off the generator.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you. We already just switched AC lines off, which solved the issue. But was curious why could that happen.